# Directory isn't found when executing os.walk for the second time

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord.py, os.walk, os.system

I have this function

```
def start(name):
for folder in next(os.walk("./hosted"))[1]:
    if folder == name:
        for file in os.listdir("./hosted/" + folder + "/scripts"):
            if file == "bot.py":
                os.chdir("./hosted/" + folder + "/scripts")
                os.system("python3.8 -c \"from bot import start; start()\" &")
                os.chdir(os.getcwd())
```

The problem is that when I try to run this function for a second time, an error is raised saying that the directory doesn't exist (it is raised at line 2). I've tried running `os.walk` outside the function twice and it worked, so it isn't the problem.

This is inside a discord bot. I need to initialize more bots from this one and this is the most useful way I found (I accept suggestions). Because discord.py is an asyncronous library, I need the `&` inside the `os.system` for the bot to keep running in the background without blocking the whole main bot, I don't know if there is another non-blocking way of executing python scripts.

Thanks.

PS: I'm running this on linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, the problem is `os.chdir(os.getcwd())` essentially does nothing -- it means "change to the current directory". If you used `old = os.getcwd()` followed by the first `chdir`, and replaced that nop with `chdir(old)`, it would probably fit your expectations.

That said, you'd probably be better off using [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to find the files you're interested in and [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to manage other processes, though [futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) or [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) might be better solutions, depending on your goals.

Comment: Wow many thanks. Do you know how could I implement what you said in this context?

Comment: I'm already using asyncio so it would be good to use that, but I don't know how to use subprocess to execute a command asyncronously and inside a directory. @Saites

Comment: [These docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#asyncio-subprocess) describe using `asyncio` for subprocesses. The first example shows running a shell command.